# "The request's session was deleted before the request completed" on heavier requests

Tags: python, django, session, server, django-sessions

In my Django project I am frequently coming across the error:

*The request's session was deleted before the request completed. The user may have logged out in a concurrent request, for example.*

This happens across a number of views and because of a number of different processes within my website. I have noticed that this error occurs on heavier requests for my local server to process, such as loading more images or returning more data from the database when calling the view associated with the current page the user is requesting.

This issue does get resolved when configuring the session engine in *settings.py*:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
```

but this causes the users session to be cleared on server refresh which is a pain during development, so another option would be needed.

I primarily use pythons sqlite3 package to execute most queries which could be a possible factor contributing to this error.

*sqlite3 connection settings:*

```
connection = sqlite3.connect(r"C:\Users\logan..\....\db.sqlite3", check_same_thread=False)
```

*django database settings in settings.py:*

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

perhaps using a different session engine would resolve this issue, or some other configuration in *settings.py*